# Add onclick event to individual divs within loop

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I am making a tic-tac-toe game. 
I would like to add individual onclick event to each div so I can add either an "X" or an "O" depending on the div I click. "O" will be added later.

JavaScript:

```
function createDivs() {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var d = document.createElement("DIV");
    document.body.appendChild(d);

    //Stuck here -borrowed some of this from a similar topic-    
    d.onclick = function() {
      return function() {
        var p = document.createElement("P");
        var x = document.createTextNode("X");
        p.appendChild(x);
        d.appendChild(p);
      }
    }(i);
    //-------------------------------------------------  

    var ii = document.createAttribute("id");
    ii.value = "D" + i;
    d.setAttributeNode(ii);
    var z = "D" + i;
    if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
      document.getElementById(z).style.clear = "left";
    }
  }
}
```

html: `<body onload="createDivs()">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `d` as argument and accept it as argument so that closure will remember it when `click` handler-function will be executed.

`d` is nothing but the `element` you are creating(`var d = document.createElement("DIV");`)

```js
function createDivs() {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var d = document.createElement("DIV");
    d.style.float = 'left';
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    d.onclick = function(d) {
      //----------------^^^ Accept d here
      return function() {
        var p = document.createElement("P");
        var x = document.createTextNode("X");
        p.appendChild(x);
        d.appendChild(p);
        d.onclick = function() {}; //Unset function after click event
      }
    }(d);
    //^^ Pass d here
    var ii = document.createAttribute("id");
    ii.value = "D" + i;
    d.setAttributeNode(ii);
    var z = "D" + i;
    if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
      document.getElementById(z).style.clear = "left";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="createDivs()">
```

**Update:** As suggested by **Barmar** in comments, value of `this` in the `event-handler` function will be the element on which event registered.

```js
function createDivs() {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var d = document.createElement("DIV");
    d.style.float = 'left';
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    d.onclick = function() {
      var p = document.createElement("P");
      var x = document.createTextNode("X");
      p.appendChild(x);
      this.appendChild(p);
      this.onclick = function() {}; //Unset function after click event
    };
    var ii = document.createAttribute("id");
    ii.value = "D" + i;
    d.setAttributeNode(ii);
    var z = "D" + i;
    if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
      document.getElementById(z).style.clear = "left";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="createDivs()">
```

Comment: That worked appreciate your time! Sorry I left out my css. I honestly don't know what the (d) after the function is doing.

Comment: @HYUTS – I have updated it.. I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Can't you just use `this` in the function to refer to the target of the event?

Comment: @Barmar – That did come in my mind while I was typing this answer but that would not highlight what was wrong with the code OP shared.. I have updated the answer with `this` as well...

Comment: @Rayon anyway I can prevent it from allowing me to keep adding more X's to the same div? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again @Rayon